# How to hold Soap sessionid when calling another method in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, session, soap

I'm trying to do some calls to webservices, but when I change the method the sessionId is different from the last method called. So I want to hold the session. I've tried many ways with no result. I am almost sure that I have to pass the session in SoapHeader method, like this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://xxx">
<soap:Header>
    <SessionHeader xmlns='http://xxx'>
        <sessionId>jsessionid=ABCDEFGHI:-1</sessionId>
    </SessionHeader>
</soap:Header>
```

With no Result...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <p118:method1:p118="http://xxx">
```

In the second method, the sessionId is a new session:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <p118:method2 xmlns:p118="http://xxx">
```

How can i do this? Thank you very much!

Comment: I send sessionId as a http parameter like this:
<SessionHeader xmlns='http://xxx'><sessionId> jsessionid=X:-1</sessionId></SessionHeader>